# Counting number of processes using shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to write a shell script that looks if a particular program is running and if it is not, it restarts the service.
Also it checks if the interface is in promiscuous mode. If it is not, it puts it in that mode.

To check if prog `xyz` is running, I can do the following on commandline

```
ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep xyz | wc -l
```

If it returns 0, progrma is not running, else it is running

Similarly to check if the interface is in promisc mode I can do the following on the command line

```
ip link show eth0 | grep -i promisc | wc -l
```

Again if return is 1, interface is in promisc mode.

The problem comes when I try to bundle it all in a shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash
SERVICE="daemonlogger"
x=$(ps -ef|grep -v grep|grep $SERVICE|wc -l)
if [ "$x" -eq 1 ]; then
 run=0
 else
 run=1
fi
IF_NAME="eth0"
y=$(ip link show $IF_NAME|grep -i promisc|wc -l)
if [ "$y" -eq 1 ]; then
 :
 else
 ifconfig $IF_NAME promisc up
fi
if [ "$run" -eq 1 ]; then
 service $SERVICE restart > /dev/NULL 2>&1
fi
echo $run
```

The output of commands if run from the command line is

```
[root@dheerajpc Desktop]# ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep daemonlogger | wc -l
0
[root@dheerajpc Desktop]# ip link show eth0 | grep -i promisc | wc -l
0
```

Here's the output of running it in debug mode

```
[root@dheerajpc Desktop]# bash -x check_daemonlogger 
+ SERVICE=daemonlogger
++ ps -ef
++ wc -l
++ grep daemonlogger
++ grep -v grep
+ x=2
+ '[' 2 -eq 1 ']'
+ run=1
+ IF_NAME=eth0
++ grep -i promisc
++ ip link show eth0
++ wc -l
+ y=0
+ '[' 0 -eq 1 ']'
+ ifconfig eth0 promisc up
+ '[' 1 -eq 1 ']'
+ service daemonlogger restart
+ echo 1
1
```

As can be seen the output of first command is not what is expected, while the output of second command is correct.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Sounds like you're assuming that only one process can have that in the command line.

Comment: That's not the point of the question. What I am asking is why does command line return 0 while shell script returns 2? Is there a syntactical problem?

Comment: Look at your script's name... that's going to be a problem.

Comment: Because your "grep daemonlogger" is also a process and will show up in the list of processes.

Comment: @Noufal: That's what the `grep -v grep` is for.

Comment: @RedBaron have you found the cause of this problem?

Comment: Well my script was named 'check_daemonlogger' and I was looking for 'daemonlogger', so when my script runs and I did a grep daemonlogger, there will be a positive match (My own script). I changed the name of the script (to anything that doesn't contain Daemonlogger) and everything was fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: What's your script called?

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly an answer but a bunch of comments.

1. You should consider using a `pidfile` rather than relying on ps, grep, wc etc. to track the process. Write the pid to a file and use that to check if the process is running. You've already hit errors with your current approach.
2. Why do you want to check the status of the interface? Can't you just switch it into promiscuous mode anyway? I haven't played with this but this is the first thing that occurred to me.